# Eclipse IDE v33 - Sticky error messages

Tags: eclipse

New computer; installed latest released Eclipse (Kepler) Force.com IDE V33 2015-04-09 version.
[image]

Project settings have ToolingApi enabled

**Create new class - valid - Save**

[image]

**Now, introduce a compile error on line 2 and SAVE**

[image]

**And here is where it gets interesting...
Fix the compile error on line 2 and create a new compile error on line 3; SAVE**

The compile error from the previous step is sticky - even though it is fixed!

[image]

**Workarounds**

1. Resolve by turning off Tooling API in project properties.

**The Question**

I don't get it -- the behavior with ToolingApi is most perplexing. Yet ToolingApi is supposed to be faster for the Eclipse SFDC developer and hence I should want to use it.  Yes, I know this is open source with SFDC distributing an ['official version'](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE). And yes, I'm aware of MavensMate but our org standard is Eclipse.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Nice to know there's a workaround. It drives me crazy. Have you submitted an Issue over on github/forcedotcom/idecore?

Comment: @sfdcfox - if it has driven you around the bend then I know I can't be too off-base :-); I just discovered this today and scrolled through the list of issues on idecore and didn't at first glance see this reported. Seemed too obvious for anyone to have missed unless everyone else never makes a compile error when they code. Will post issue later if no one else has anything substantive.

Comment: @sfdcfox this appears to be an acknowledged issue on github: https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/112 (May 31) -- I must not have looked hard enough. Another workaround is to right click on Errors and delete

Comment: @crop1645 That you can fix it by clearing the errors in the IDE makes it sound more like an Eclipse/plugin issue than a Tooling API issue.