# Salesforce Eclipse Plugin - Save errors

Tags: apex, error, eclipse

When I save to server from the Eclipse Salesforce plugin, and there are save errors, I only get warned about one of them.

So I fix it.

When I save again, if there are more errors, it will warn me about one more error, but *the original error is still there*, so no there are 2 warnings.

So I fix again, save again, and if there is still another error to fix *there are now 3 warnings* - the 2 I'v already fixed, and one more.

After a while, I have so many warnings that I lose track of which ones are real and which are left-over phantoms. At times like these I long for the good old days when I was a Java developer.

Is the plugin really that truly dreadful, not fit-for-purpose, or do I have a config problem somewhere? I'm on Eclipse Mars on Linux. Are there any viable alternatives? (and please, not the dev console! ugh!)

Comment: You could raise an issue [https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues) if you are using the current version. Many people recommend using [MavensMate](http://mavensmate.com/) instead.

Comment: ah, I reported the same issue here -- http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81867/eclipse-ide-v33-sticky-error-messages - with workarounds and Known Issue