# Use tooling API deploy path when possible

Tags: ide, tooling-api

I have just notice that there is a check-box "Use tooling API deploy path when possible" in Eclipse Force.com project settings. See the screenshot:

[image]

Can not find any documentation regarding this configuration option. Does this allow to switch between Tooling API and Metadata API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this toggles between using the Tooling API (checked) and the Metadata API (unchecked).

I've found [several](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/53) posts from Nick Chen (Salesforce) confirming this.

> Are you deploying through the Tooling API or Metadata API. You can right-click on the Project and then select Force.com > Project Properties. In the dialog that pops-up, select Force.com > Deployment Options to toggle between the two. [Source](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/29)

Found in the [source](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/blob/master/com.salesforce.ide.ui/src/com/salesforce/ide/ui/internal/utils/messages.properties#L208):

```
DeploymentOptions_UseToolingAPI=Use Tooling API deploy path when possible
```

Which leads to the [UI](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/blob/514b6e9d51a069f3ccbf4f02ecf406fdbd1229db/com.salesforce.ide.ui/src/com/salesforce/ide/ui/properties/DeploymentOptions.java#L74):

```
 preferToolingDeploymentCheckbox.setText(UIMessages.getString("DeploymentOptions_UseToolingAPI"));
```

It terms of actually changing how the deployment occurs. This happens in the [BuilderController](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/blob/514b6e9d51a069f3ccbf4f02ecf406fdbd1229db/com.salesforce.ide.core/src/com/salesforce/ide/core/project/BuilderController.java#L89).

```
public void build(ComponentList saveComponentList, IProject project, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws Exception {
    ForceProject forceProject =
            ContainerDelegate.getInstance().getServiceLocator().getProjectService().getForceProject(project);

    // If the user has opted for Tooling API and it's applicable, use the faster Tooling API route
    if (forceProject.getPreferToolingDeployment() && isDeployableThroughToolingAPI(saveComponentList, forceProject)) {
        buildThroughTooling(saveComponentList, project, forceProject, monitor);
    } else { // Fallback to the Metadata API that supports all types
        buildThroughMetadata(saveComponentList, project, forceProject, monitor);
    }
}
```

The API version being deployed needs to meet the minimum version supported by the Tooling API and that all the components meet the requirements for [isDeployableThroughContainerAsyncRequest()](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/blob/514b6e9d51a069f3ccbf4f02ecf406fdbd1229db/com.salesforce.ide.core/src/com/salesforce/ide/core/model/ComponentList.java#L444). The latter being that the tooling API supports all the components being deployed and that those components already exist in Salesforce. The tooling API won't be used to create new components.

Comment: Does it fall back to metadata API if tooling API fails? Curious if the "When Possible" is a poor choice of words or if it actually means what you could infer it means

Comment: there's also some related information here on tooling API issues: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81867/eclipse-ide-v33-sticky-error-messages

Comment: @Eric I dived a bit deeper into the code. It looks like it will use the Tooling API if - the API version is high enough, all the components are supported by the tooling API, and all the components already exist in Salesforce (have IDs).

Comment: @Eric It doesn't fallback if it fails; it surfaces an error. The only way to fix the error (today) is to disable the Tooling API deploy path. Fortunately, such bugs are obscure and rare enough that you'd normally want to use the Tooling API.

Comment: @DanielBallinger thank you for such detailed comment. I face some issues with using of Tooling API that I did not see before. For instance if I update local copy from git and Force.com -> Work Online option is set, eclipse deploy local copy and override server copy.
With metadata API as a rule it throws and exception like 'There some changes on a server, please refresh from server before save'

Do you know is there any difference between Tooling and Metadata in handling  of deployment versioning?

Comment: @Yury I'd suggest asking this as a new question. It will make it easier to track the answers etc... Feel free to link to the new question from a comment here.

Comment: Created separate question about versioning in Metadata and Tooling - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100678/versioning-difference-between-metadata-and-tooling